# iPhone - Display smoothly 2 successive modal view controller

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, conflict, modalviewcontroller, dismiss

I'm searching a way to be able to display one modal view controller after another one, and make the second appear while the first is disapearing.

The problem is that the dismiss call that is done inside the first modalviewcontroller applies to both and SecondController is never shown.

Putting the first dismiss before or after the parent call does not change anything.
If first dismiss is set wih animate= NO, everything works fine. But I need the animation.

I planned to do that this way, but the problem is that the dismiss call that is done inside the first modalviewcontroller applies to both and SecondController is never shown.

I don't understand why because each modal view has its own navigationcontrollers, so they shouldn't collide.

I tried another way by showing the second modal view with a NSTimer after 0.5 sec, but it's not satisfying : the second appears when the first has completely disapeared. Not smooth at all... If I set the delay less than 0.5 sec, the second modal view never shows up. And using such a timer to make this does not seem to be a good way of coding.

## Main.m

```
- (void) entry {

    FirstController *nextWindow = [[FirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"theNIB" bundle:nil];

    nextWindow.caller = self;

    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextWindow];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    [nextWindow release];
    [navController release];
}


- (void) thingsDoneInFirstModalController:(OBJECT)returnValue retval2:(OBJECT2)returnValue2 {
    [self display2ndController];
}

- (void) display2ndController {

    SecondController *nextWindow;

    nextWindow = [[SecondController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIB2" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextWindow];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [navController release];
    [nextWindow release];
}
```

## 1st ModalViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.caller thingsDoneInFirstModalController:theResult retval2:someMoreResult];
}
```

Do you know a way to make this possible (make the second view appears while the first one is disappearing), with some code for example ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating some dummy ViewController, and present your second one using it.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more your answer please ?

Comment: well, it seems I was wrong, it is not possible to preset/dismiss 2 viewcontrollers simultaneously. Here is what i've got   2011-01-26 17:38:55.380 test[4415:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from <UIViewController: 0x4e17500> to <UIViewController: 0x4e17590> while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed'

Comment: so you can do that using simple UIView animation, without modal view controllers. It would work for sure